# How to allow zoom in mobile in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I want to know if there is some way to allow doing zoom in mobile browsers when the webpage is on fullscreen mode.

Comment: I said " mobile browsers" if there is way to make it works in all of them. But my priorities are chrome and firefox.

Comment: the content in chrome is already zoom-able

Comment: well i'm testing my web and when I go to fullscreen mode I cannot do zoom with chrome or firefox in android while I can without the fullscreen mode

Comment: already this functionality is available in iPhone or iPad browser.

Comment: Nice Mihir Oza, unfortunately I cannot test it in iOS enviroments so I cannot be sure. I only can check it on android browsers. Thank you for the information.

Comment: it is 2020 and I can't do it on chrome android ... is there a workaround ?